# Nginx http_accept cannot be mapped to variable for content-negotiation

Tags: nginx, mime-types, content-type

The goal is to get map the `Content-Type` value to a file type using -

```
# nginx.conf
map $http_accept $suffix {
    "~*turtle" ".ttl";
    default    "DEFAULT";
}
```

which is handled by -

```
# sites-available/site
location /ontologies {
    root /folder;
    add_header Vary Accept;
    add_header X-debug-accept "$http_accept";
    add_header X-debug-suffix "$suffix";
    try_files $uri$suffix $uri =404;
}
```

However, the response always gives -

```
# curl -I -H "Content-type: text/turtle" URL
http_accept = */*
suffix      = DEFAULT, which is actually (blank)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing the wrong header. You should be using `$http_content_type` and not `$http_accept`

```
# curl -v -I -H "Content-type: text/turtle" URL
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/turtle
```

As you can see you passed `Content-Type` and not `Accept`. So based on which header you need use the correct variable. Either `$http_content_type` or `$http_accept`